# CSS submenu option jumps around

Tags: css, menu, submenu

I have a CSS menu on this page: http://itos3test.notexa.be/itos3test/customer-service-oplossingen/. When you hover over "*rol van het contact center*" or "*Bedrijfs doelstellingen*" you can see that the submenu has 2 rows.

When I now hover over the third submenu ("*Verkoop fondsenwerving*" or "*Klanten-Trouw verhogen*") the fourth submenu jumps to the right, the gap between the first and second row becomes smaller and the items after the fourth display on a third row.

I tried searching for the css that is causing this with firebug, and as far as I can see the containers are all of the correct size. Maybe it inherits something, or I made a horrible mistake in the css, but I just can't see it.

The CSS code:

```
/* style main menu */

ul.shortcode_menu.solution-finder {
    display: inline;
}

ul.shortcode_menu.solution-finder li {
    list-style: none;
    background: linear-gradient(#00A7FF 3.8%, #27027B) repeat scroll 0 0 #00A7FF;
    border-radius: 2px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
    padding: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}

ul.shortcode_menu.solution-finder li:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(#54575A, #54575A) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(106, 115, 123, 0.5);
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(106, 115, 123, 0.5);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(106, 115, 123, 0.5);
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

ul.shortcode_menu.solution-finder li a {
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 99%;
    height: 65px;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000000;
}

ul.shortcode_menu.solution-finder li:hover a {
    opacity: 0.9;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
}

/* style sub menus */

ul.shortcode_menu.solution-finder li ul.sub-menu {
    width: 600px;
}

ul.shortcode_menu.solution-finder li ul.sub-menu li {
    display: inline-block !important;
    list-style: none;
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    margin-right: 0.2em;
    margin-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #EEE;
}

ul.shortcode_menu.solution-finder li ul.sub-menu li:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: none; 
}

ul.shortcode_menu.solution-finder li ul.sub-menu li a {
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 99%;
    height: 65px;
/*    background: linear-gradient(#00A7FF 3.8%, #27027B) repeat scroll 0 0 #00A7FF;*/
    display: block;

}

ul.shortcode_menu.solution-finder li ul.sub-menu li:hover a {
/*  opacity: 0.9;
    background: linear-gradient(#54575A, #54575A) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(106, 115, 123, 0.5);
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(106, 115, 123, 0.5);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(106, 115, 123, 0.5);
    margin-bottom: 0;*/

}
```

Anybody got an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Found it: margin-bottom: 0 was the problem